# Firebase Cloud Firestore: Sealed classes in custom objects in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
```

for testing the Firestore-Database SDK with Kotlin in version 1.3.50.

For read/write tests I created a simple data class:

```
data class Location(
    val uuid: String? = null,
    val name: String? = null
)
```

which is working fine and smooth, like expected.

But going a little bit deeper to extend the data class with Kotlin's sealed classes leads to problems in serialization:

```
data class Location(
    val uuid: String? = null,
    val name: String? = null,
    val locationProperty: LocationProperty? = null
)

sealed class LocationProperty {

    data class TextProperty(
        val text: String? = null
    ) : LocationProperty()
}
```

While writing to the database works still fine, the app throws an exception while serializing the result:

```
document.toObject(Location::class.java)
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found
on class com.abc.def.LocationProperty
```

In the Firestore frontend I saw that my sealed class is saved as a `Map` in the NoSQL-database and the raw-data of the received `DocumentSnapshot` looks like this

```
(locationProperty =>ArraySortedMap{(text=>My entered text)}
```

so this might cause the error.

Is there any way to solve this issue, maybe by providing custom serializer when reading or writing data to the Firestore if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to use a sealed class with `toObject()`.  That's because sealed classes themselves don't have enough information to know what properties you actually want to read and write.  Only the concrete classes that subclass the sealed class are going to work, as reflection can be used to determine all of their properties at runtime.

Firestore's object serialization from class reflection simply isn't suited for this particular use case.  You should instead provide your data to save as a `Map<String, *>`.  When reading the document, the data will also show up the same way.  That's because Firestore internally converts your object to and from a Map.  This is going to involve writing a bunch of code to read and write the entries of that Map using the properties of the object, and that's actually pretty normal.

The Firestore SDK currently doesn't have any concept of a "serializer" plugin that lets you intercept objects being serialized in order to perform the conversion.  You have to serialize to a Map before writing the document, and you have to deserialize from a Map when reading the document back.

Comment: thanks for this answer I have always known about the possibility of using a Map for this but I have spent quite while looking for a more elegant/type-safe way to to store/get data from firebase. Knowing that maps are the way to go allows me to move on